# ¿Qué son los prototipos en JavaScript y para qué sirven?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber qué son los **prototipos** en JavaScript y cómo los puedo usar o si existe algún tipo de beneficio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como nota inicial, la *POO* de `JavaScript` se encuentra basada en prototipos y no en clases. Para ver más información sobre `prototype-based OOP` vrs. `class-based OOP`puedes visitar el siguiente **[link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110936/what-are-the-advantages-of-prototype-based-oop-over-class-based-oop)**(en inglés).

Los prototipos son un conjunto de normas para integrar **Programación Orientada a Objetos** en `JavaScript`. Entonces, siguiendo estas reglas nosotros debemos ser capaces de crear las distintas metodologías de la Orientación a Objetos:

- Herencia
- Encapsulamiento
- Abstracción
- Polimorfismo

Por supuesto, no todas la metodologías están disponibles.

### ¿Cómo puedo utilizarlos prototipos?

**ECMAScript 5**

Para crear una clase:

```
function Polygon(height, width){
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}
```

Para heredar sobre una clase base:

```
function Square(side){
  this.prototype = Object.create(Polygon.prototype);
  Polygon.call(this, side, side);

  this.getArea = function(){
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

**ECMAScript 6**

Para crear una clase:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Para heredar de una clase base:

```
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(side) {
    super(side, side);
  }
  getArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

Ya con esto podemos crear una instancia con:

```
var square = new Square(5);
// debe imprimir 25
console.log(square.getArea());
```

Ejemplos tomados de **[Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)**.

### Beneficios

- Disponer de programación de alto nivel.
- Disponer de diferentes formas de crear objetos.
- Tener herencia en las propiedades y métodos.
- Básicamente los beneficios de disponer de prototipos en `JavaScript` es la posibilidad de utilizar la Programación Orientada a Objetos como metodología de Software.

Comment: En el ejemplo de ES5, has inicializado los campos de width y height directamente, sin llamar al constructor del prototipo. Pero es posible que ese constructor tenga más lógico que sea difícil—o aún imposible (si tiene una referencia a un closure que ya no está accesible). ¿Es posible llamar al constructor del clase base en ES5? y ¿cómo?

Comment: @WChargin Estoy de acuerdo contigo, el constructor para ES5 no parece tener lógica, lo resolveré lo antes posible.

Comment: @WChargin Cada función en `JavaScript` tiene el método `call`. Con esto puedes llamar al constructor padre para la reutilización de código. [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Acabo de modificar el ejemplo utilizando el método `call`.

Comment: En pocas palabras `this` es lo que diferencia una clase de una función, cierto?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas No necesariamente, `this` se puede utilizar incluso sin estar dentro de una función o clase. Su comportamiento o valor depende de cómo es llamada. Por ejemplo, en caso de utilizar `this` en el entorno global, `this` representa a `window`, en caso de usarse bajo la expresión `new`,  representa la instancia del objeto actual. Entonces, en términos generales, representa el `scope` actual. [Más información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this).

Answer (score 9):

Todos los objetos en JavaScript tienen una propiedad especial llamada `prototype` que es una referencia a otro objeto.

¿Para qué es útil?, veamos un ejemplo:

```
var miObjeto = {
  foo: 5
}
console.log(miObjeto.foo); // 5
```

Aquí creamos un objeto llamado `miObjeto`, definimos una propiedad `foo` con el valor de 5 e imprimimos el valor de esta variable. Claramente el resultado es 5, pero ¿qué pasa cuando el objeto **no tiene** una variable `foo`?. JavaScript tratará de encontrarla en el `prototype` de este objeto, y así sucesivamente hasta que la encuentre o llegue al final de la cadena de prototipo.

Esta cadena de prototipo nos **permite simular herencia** (recordemos que en JavaScript no existe la herencia basada en clases), si queremos agregar métodos o propiedades a un objeto podemos hacerlo mediante el `prototype`.

Consideremos la siguiente función `Persona`:

```
function Persona(nombre, edad) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.edad = edad;
}
```

El prototipo de esta función es `Persona.prototype` y podemos añadirle más métodos o propiedades de las que tiene originalmente:

```
Persona.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "[Persona: " + this.nombre + "]";
}

Persona.prototype.saludar = function() {
  console.log("Hola mi nombre es: " + this.nombre);
}
```

Ahora vamos a crear un objeto `p` de tipo `Persona` con `new`, es este punto el prototipo de `p` es igual `Persona.prototype`:

```
var p = new Persona("John", 33);
console.log(p.nombre); // propiedad del objeto
console.log(p.toString()); // propiedad no encontrada directamente en el objeto
```

Por esta razón al invocar el método `toString` a pesar de que no es un método directo de `p`, JavaScript busca en el prototipo de `p` y sí lo encuentra y todo funciona correctamente.

En cualquier momento podemos consultar el prototipo de un objeto con `Object.getPrototypeOf`, para nuestro caso particular:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === Persona.prototype; // true
```

Por último es importante notar que hay una propiedad **no estándar** para obtener el prototipo de un objeto llamada `__proto__`, sin embargo su uso debe ser evitado.

Comment: creo que es de las mejores explicaciones que he leído al respecto. Claro, conciso y práctico. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Los prototipos son objetos que pueden tener propiedades (funciones y métodos), ademas pueden ser utilizados por otros objetos para heredar sus propiedades, esto es muy útil para encapsular y reutilizar el código, esto te da la posibilidad de adaptar tus códigos al diseño orientada a objetos.

En JavaScript todo lo que no sean tipos primitivos (`undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `number` o `string`) son objetos y pueden ser usados como prototipos para crear otros objetos.