# ¿Qué es prototype en javascript y cual es su herencia?

Tags: javascript

¿Cuál es la funcionalidad de `.prototype` en Javascript, cuál es su propósito y qué herencia tiene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype sirve para extender una funcion o en caso de verlo como una clase un prototype es un metodo de la clase de la que se extiende y hereda los valores de la clase.

[Aqui veras un post de otro compañero que lo explica bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2012/qu%C3%A9-son-los-prototipos-en-javascript-y-para-qu%C3%A9-sirven)