# Cambiar método de un objeto

Tags: javascript, método

Me gustaría saber como modificar un método llamado "operation" que tengo asociado a un objeto, el método del objeto es el siguiente:

```
operation: function(input) {
    if (input == true) {
        return !input;
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Y me gustaría cambiarlo por este otro:

```
operation: function(input) {
    return input;
}
```

He probado a cambiarlo de la misma forma con la que cambio atributos cómo posición, tamaño, etc. pero produce un error. La forma con la que puedo modificar por ejemplo la posición de un objeto es la siguiente:

```
objecto.position(100, 0)
```

¿Alguien sabe como modificar métodos asociados a objetos y como puedo modificar el método "operation"?

Muchas gracias.

Pd: Estoy usando librerías jquery y joint

Comment: con prototype, pero con lo que tienes no puedo ayudarte

Comment: que es prototype??

Comment: Los prototipos son un conjunto de normas para integrar Programación Orientada a Objetos en JavaScript. Entonces, siguiendo estas reglas nosotros debemos ser capaces de crear las distintas metodologías de la Orientación a Objetos.                                      Aquí en stack tienes una respuesta que te puede orientar hacia los prototype. [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2012/qu%C3%A9-son-los-prototipos-en-javascript-y-para-qu%C3%A9-sirven](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2012/qu%C3%A9-son-los-prototipos-en-javascript-y-para-qu%C3%A9-sirven) Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambiar un método por otro en javascript se puede hacer de varias formas,
las que yo conozco son las siguiente:

cambiando el método directamente en el objeto por asignación:

1 suponiendo que este es my objeto

```
    var obj={
        name:'nombre',
        age:'age',
        operation:function(input) {
            if (input == true) {
                return !input;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        }
    }
```

para cambiar el método solo hay que reasignarle a operation la nueva función

```
    obj.operation=function(input) {
        return input;
    }
```

2 Cambiar el método en el prototipo de la clase del objeto.

Suponiendo que esta es mi clase

```
    class myClass{
        constructor(name,age){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
        }
    }
```

Los métodos los creo en el prototype

```
    myClass.prototype.operation=function(input) {
        if (input == true) {
            return !input;
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

declaro el objeto

```
    var obj=new myClass('name','age');
```

si cambio el método en el prototype va a cambiar para cada uno de los objetos de la clase

```
    myClass.prototype.operation=function(input) {
        return input;
    }
```

pero si lo cambio desde el objeto solo va a cambiar para ese objeto

```
    obj.operation=function(input) {
        return input;
    }
```

Acá hay varias entradas donde se describe el uso de objetos y prototipos en js https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript